# Grail mail plugin - unable to add in multiple TO addresses?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

New to grails world.  I am having issues passing the comma seperated form values from a form into the 'TO' properties of the grails mail plugin. no matter what I try I can seem to get it to an array or accept multiple email addresses.

Im getting the following error; I have removed the domain names so please disregard them.

```
Could not parse mail; nested exception is javax.mail.internet.AddressException:
Illegal address in string ``"ian@email.com","ian@otheremail.com"''
```

Scratching head now, any ideas of where I am going wrong with the below code. I'm completely stumped.!!

in emailpublication GSP form I have. these fields are automatically populated from the database and id of document.

```
<g:form action="emailpublication">

<g:field type="text" name="whogetsemail" value="${publicationInstance?.portfolio?.emailtemplates?.toemailtemplate}" /> 
<g:field type="text" name="publicationName" value="${publicationInstance?.publicationName}" />
<g:textArea type="text" name="publicationContent" value="${publicationInstance?.publicationContent}" cols="20" rows="20"/> 
<g:hiddenField name="id" value="${publicationInstance?.id}" />

<input type="submit" value="Send Email"/>
</g:form>
```

In Publication controller I have the following; I need to send TO on one or more email address populated from the whogetsemail field in the emailpublication gsp form

```
def emailpublication(){

  List<String> recipients = request.getParameterValues("whogetsemail")
    try {
     sendMail{
             to  (recipients.toArray())
             from "ineilsen@emailaddress.com"
             subject params.publicationName
             text params.emailbodyheader + "\n"+"\n" + params.publicationContent + "\n"+"\n" + params.footeremailtemplate
         }

    }
    catch (MailException e) {
        log.error "Failed to send emails: $e.message", e
    }
    catch (MessagingException e) {
        log.error "Failed to send emails: $e.message", e
    }
    redirect(uri: "/publication/show/${params}")
            flash.message = "${params.publicationName} sent to ${params.emailto}"
}
```

Thanks all, look forward to replies, Im frustrated with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin supports multiple addresses, and they can be in an `Object[]` array or a `List`. But you're getting a single comma-delimited string since there's only one `whogetsemail` field. `request.getParameterValues()` only returns multiple values if there are multiple inputs with the same name.

It should work if you change it to this:

```
List<String> recipients = params.whogetsemail.split(',').collect { it.trim() }
```

and

```
to recipients
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the parenthesis around the to address:

```
to  recipients.toArray()
```

I do exactly this in lot's of places...

Comment: negative ghost rider - still get error Could not parse mail; nested exception is javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``"ian@email.com","ian@email.com"''

Comment: See Burt's answer.  I had actually just noticed that it's a single `whogetsemail` field, not multiple fields.  But awesome Top Gun reference!